# Sass in Angular 2 and webpack not working

Tags: sass, angular, webpack

I am acting according to sass-loader package:
In my webconfig I have:

```
{
        loaders: [
            {
                test: /\.scss$/,
                loaders: ["style", "css", "sass"]
            }
        ]
    }
```

In the module I import the scss like this:

```
 styles:  require('./home.scss') ,
```

Scss file looks like this:

```
$font-stack:    Helvetica, sans-serif;
$primary-color: #333;

md-card {
font: 100% $font-stack;
color: $primary-color;
}
```

Unfortunately, when I run the app, the following happens:

```
ERROR in ./src/app/home/home.scss
Module parse failed: C:\src\app\home\home.scss Line 1: Unexpected token :
You may need an appropriate loader to handle this file type.
| $font-stack:    Helvetica, sans-serif;
| $primary-color: #333;
|
@ ./src/app/home/home.component.ts 49:20-42
```

I think everything should be ok, when it fails then?

Comment: Don't know if that's the issue, but `styles` in the [component metadata](https://angular.io/docs/ts/latest/api/core/ComponentMetadata-class.html#!#styles-anchor) definition object should be an array: `styles:  [require('./home.scss')],`

Comment: Yes, I also tried with that syntax, it does not work either.

Answer (score 2):

I recommend the raw-loader to import styles into angular2 components: https://github.com/webpack/raw-loader

```
...
loaders: [
    {
        test: /\.scss$/,
        loaders: ['raw-loader', 'sass-loader']
     }
]
...
```

Also `styles` should be an Array!

```
...
styles: [ require('./home.scss') ],
...
```

Also see: https://github.com/AngularClass/angular2-webpack-starter/wiki/How-to-include-SCSS-in-components

BTW: You can use the raw-loader for importing templates, too.

Comment: This solutions works only for dev, try build with ['raw-loader', 'sass-loader'] only, I cant find solution with avoid require in component.

Comment: @UlandNimblehoof try: https://www.npmjs.com/package/@ngtools/webpack, its a complete replacement for the tsc, supports autoimporting templates/styles and aot compiling